# Is there a way to quickly locate one's own space ship in No Man's Sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've just started playing No Man's Sky, on PlayStation 4; having found the spaceship as part of the initial beginning of the game, I then wandered off to explore and mine various resources.

Given the title of this question you'd be absolutely correct in assuming I got lost, or lost sight of my ship and now need to find my way back. I've seen various mentions of activating a beacon, but assuming that requires construction ([Beacon - No Man's Sky Wiki](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Beacon)) I have no blueprints for such and, if it's a function of my spaceship I seem unable to access said function and the spaceship itself is out of range.

Is there some means or in-game function that I'm overlooking?

Comment: I know that after repairing your ship for the first time, it will have a marker on your HUD of where it is after that, however, during the beginning of the game when you still have yet to repair it, I'm not sure if that marker is present.

Comment: My apologies for the delay in responding, but I got quite frustrated and quit out of the game. After finding the ship, and making an initial repair, the marker seemed to disappear from the HUD. Reloading from saves, before quitting, didn't seem to resolve anything, so I'm assuming it wasn't a glitch.

Comment: I'm a beginner too. Maybe pressing the "SCAN" button can help? But I am not sure if this really reveals the location of your ship.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to. Admittedly I don't have the analysis visor yet, so I can't say with any certainty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Craft the analysis visor. After that, you should have a marker on your HUD pointing to your vessel.

Usually, you get the quest to craft the visor as soon as you wander too far off from the starship.

*Once you have repaired the starter vessel*, there is an icon looking like a fighter jet indicating its position on your HUD. Alternatively, you can summon the starship by pressing <kbd>X</kbd>, and scrolling left to "Summon Starship". That way you can also switch vessels, should you have acquired more then one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the quick menu to summon your ship to your location.

It's <kbd>X</kbd> on PC and I think D-Pad Down on Console. Then you can scroll to the left, until you see the ship icon, and it will allow you to summon your ship directly to where you want it.

Comment: You can not summon the ship before it is repaired, tho.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me I wondered away collecting stuff then got totally lost got a heap of rewards for exploring and discovering new places but had no idea how to find my ship.  I also stupidly created a new save location hell and gone from my space ship.  But when I did die, when I was brought back in game at the new save point all of a sudden there was a icon on my screen showing where my spaceship was and how far away it was, so I just had to follow it back to my ship.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You craft carbon nano tubes from carbon. Fairly common mineral. Then use carbon nano tubes to install analysis visor then ur ship will show up on ur hud. Same thing happened to me.